# Fibrant Replacement Functor: its action on morphisms

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

I'm reading the below in Model Categories by Hovey.

[image]

And before we go further, here is the definition of model category I am working with:

[image]

From reading the answer from [Fibrant replacement functor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796306/fibrant-replacement-functor), I know how $Q$ acts on objects, but I'm still not sure how it acts on morphism.

My guess would be the following.

Let's denote $\phi$ as the initial object. I want to know what is $Q(f \colon X \rightarrow Y)$.

Consider the factorization of $i_1 \colon \phi \rightarrow Y$ by $i_1 = \beta(g) \alpha(g)$ and the factorization of $i_2 \colon \phi \rightarrow X$ by $i_2 = \beta(h) \alpha(h)$, where $\alpha(g) \colon \phi \rightarrow QY$ and $\alpha(h) \colon \phi \rightarrow QX$.

We may consider the following commutative square.

[image]

$\alpha(h)$ is a cofibration, and $\beta(g)$ is trivial fibration, so there is a lift $k \colon QX \rightarrow QY$.

Now, I want to say $Qf = k$, but this lift may not be unique, so this poses a problem.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There is no "the" fibrant replacement functor. The definition is not enough to pin it down uniquely, not even up to isomorphism. So there isn't much you can say about its action on morphisms.

Comment: @ZhenLin : Hovey works with functorial factorizations, so there *is* a fibrant replacement functor

Comment: Yes, there is _a_ fibrant replacement functor, and with Hovey's definition of model category you could even call it _the_ fibrant replacement functor if you want, but it is basically an arbitrary choice. There is a huge difference between fibrant replacement functors and, say, limit functors, which are well defined up to isomorphism.

Comment: @ZhenLin : Yes of course, but my guess is that the OP doesn't get how to define that functor - that's how I interpreted the question (and that's the question I answered)

Comment: Ah, I missed that possibility. Too many years knowing this stuff, one forgets where one started...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote "fibrant replacement functor", but used the notation $Q$, which is the notation for the cofibrant replacement functor. I went with the the fibrant one, but of course, for $Q$, the story is entirely dual.

Well if $f: X\to Y$, you have a morphism of morphisms:

$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} X @>>> Y \\
@VpVV @VqVV \\
*@>>> *\end{CD}$

and since $(\gamma,\delta)$ is by assumption a functorial factorization, you get a map $\gamma(p)\to \gamma(q)$, that is, a commutative square:

$\begin{CD}X @>>> Y \\
@V\gamma(p)VV @V\gamma(q)VV \\
R(X) @>>> R(Y)\end{CD}$

with $R(X) \to R(Y)$ being given as *part of the data* of $\gamma((f,id_*))$ (note that in $\gamma(p)$, we see $p$ as an *object* of the arrow category, while in $\gamma((f,id_*))$, $(f,id_*)$ is an arrow in the arrow category)

The fact that this map $R(f): R(X)\to R(Y)$ makes $R$ into a functor follows from the fact that $\gamma$ is a functor and that $(g,id_*)\circ (f,id_*)= (g\circ f,id_*)$

Comment: thanks, this helped a lot!

Comment: quick question, does anything change if you use $\delta$ instead?

Comment: If you use $\delta$, you don't get a fibrant replacement

Comment: sorry to keep asking you questions, so feel free to ignore. But I'm having trouble convincing myself that $R$ preserves weak equivalences. This should be clear if the map from $X$ to $Y$ in the second commutative square is $f$, but I don't see why that would always be the case. Thanks.

Comment: It is $f$, by definition of functorial factorization (although maybe the was not given in Hovey's book, I don't remember)

Comment: what part of definition would that be? Hovey just defines it as a pair of functors $(\alpha, \beta)$ such that for all $f$, $f = \beta(f) \alpha(f)$.

Comment: I just had a look and you're right, that's all that's stated in the definition. There are two options, though I'm not sure which is the correct one : 1- Hovey misstated the definition, and you're actually asking that $\alpha, \beta$ act nicely on morphisms (I'll let you define "nicely" here); 2- it can actually be deduced from the definition that they *do* act nicely. I'm not sure, but I bet it's option 1.

Comment: maybe this is relevant? I don't really understand it though: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179279/how-was-the-functorial-factorization-axiom-frequently-misstated

Comment: Yes, it is definitely relevant. The point is that Hovey's requirement only mentions objects ($f$ is an *object* in the arrow category), whereas it should say something about the morphisms too. Specifically it should say precisely that the map $X\to Y$ you get is $f$. See e.g. the nLab for a better definition : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functorial+factorization  (section "concrete explicit")

Comment: In the answer you pointed to, the relevant passage is Tim's edit to his answer (and he seems to say I was right about option 1 : Hovey did make a mistake, thinking something went "without saying")

Comment: Thanks so much! Everything's clear now.